# How to prove that infimum of this set is $0$

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

> How do I prove that the infimum of the set $A=\{x+\frac{1}{n}:x\in(0,1),n\in\mathbb{Z^+}\}$ is $0$?

Clearly $0$ is a lower bound of A since $1/n$ is greater than $0$ for all $n$. How do I show that any real number $K>0$ is not also a lower bound, hence making $0$ the infimum?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $\frac K2+\frac1n\lt K$ if $n$ is large enough.

Answer (score 1):

It remains to show that for a given $\epsilon>0$ there are $x\in(0,1)$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ such that
$$ x+\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon.$$
Note that the above inequality is implied by $x<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{n}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Can you take it from here?